# ECONNREFUSED for proxy request from localhost to another localhost

Tags: javascript, php, angular, npm, econnrefused

To begin, I'm new to angular and I'm following a [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/2OHbjep_WjQ) step by step. 
I've been stuck on this issue for nearly 2 weeks and have spent many hours looking for solutions in other similar forums. I realize this is a common error, but after trying a couple dozen or so solutions but finding no success I figure I may as well post my experience and maybe it can shed some light on this problem many of us seem to be having.

## The Issue

The error occurs while following along for the "Angular Tutorial #13" part of the video which starts around 1:42:00. I follow all steps exactly as shown in the video but I encounter the following error message in the terminal in which I run "npm start" : 
`[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/file.php from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:1234 (ECONNREFUSED)`
My package.json scripts for "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json"
and my proxyconfig.json contains:

```
{
    "/api":{
        "target": "http://localhost:1234",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

In CMD I navigate to the folder "intro2angular" which is the root of "/test/api/file.php" and I run 
`php -S localhost:1234` prior to running `npm start` in the powershell in VisualStudioCode. Then I run `npm start`. Code compiles successfully. In Chrome, if I go to `http://localhost:1234/test/api/file.php` then the file is displayed in the browser. **However**, if I go to `http://localhost:4200` and click an anchor which executes the code to request *file.php* then the `[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/file.php from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:1234 (ECONNREFUSED)` error is displayed in terminal. In the *Network* tab of Developer Tools in Chrome, when I check the Headers for *file.php* I see the follow:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/api/file.php
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 504 Gateway Timeout
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Forgive me for being verbose in explaining every step I followed, but since I've seen several similar forum posts regarding the ECONNREFUSED error being raised while trying to use a proxy, I thought that including every minor detail may be necessary to distinguish the source of the error in this instance. If any more details/code is necessary I'm more than happy to include it.

### Solutions I've tried thus far

Note that this is not a complete list, I've tried several other solutions but these seem to be the most common which have worked for others. Also, I'm not saying that I wouldn't give these solutions another try as I am open to any and all suggestions.

1. specifying random localhost ports for both the angular app and file.php
2. using `setTimeout` to add a delay to the `.getData()` function call
3. disabling firewall
4. including the option `"pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}` to *proxyconfig.json*

I appreciate any and all help/suggestions/discussions around this issue as I've had no success on my own and I am unable to continue with the angular tutorial until this issue is resolved. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and searched for a solution for ages...

In my case it helped to provide the IP of localhost, instead of "localhost".

So change your proxy-config to this:

```
{
    "/api":{
        "target": "http://127.0.0.1:1234",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And also try using "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json" instead of the npm start version. I read that sometimes the package.json config-part got ignored for some people.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Angular and PHP built in server, you have to use IP addresses on both sides. So something like: `"target": "http://127.0.0.1:8000"` on Angular side + something like `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public` on PHP side.

Found this tip here: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/econnrefused-error-during-learn-angular-freecodecamp-org-video/245739

Comment: Changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` on both Angular and PHP side is what fixed it for me. Thanks!